# Keychain iOS not always storing values

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I´m developing a couple of iOS applications and i need to share a element between them, that i want to store in the keychain.
This element is used in a complex login process with 3 or 4 steps, in each one i need to read the value from the keychain, to do this i used the code bellow:

```
- (NSString *)installationToken
{
    KeychainItemWrapper *kw = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"uuid" accessGroup:@"yyyyy.xxxxxxxxxxx"];   

    if (![kw objectForKey:(NSString*)kSecAttrAccount] || [[kw objectForKey:(NSString*)kSecAttrAccount] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *result;

        CFUUIDRef uuid;
        CFStringRef uuidStr;

        uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        assert(uuid != NULL);

        uuidStr = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
        assert(uuidStr != NULL);

        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", uuidStr];
        assert(result != nil);

        CFRelease(uuidStr);
        CFRelease(uuid);

        [kw setObject:result forKey:(NSString*)kSecAttrAccount];

        return result;
    } else {
        return [kw objectForKey:(NSString*)kSecAttrAccount];
    }

}
```

This all works well in almost every device but in some, users are complaining. So, i checked what my server is receiving, and saw that different values are being sent.
I checked the code and in no other place i'm acessing/emptying this keychain element, what can be wrong with this? For the majority of devices this works like a charm but for some reason, in some devices, they aren't storing or retrieving well from the keychain.
The problem happens in different invocation in the same application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apples' sample code for KeyChainWrapper, then main problem is sometimes randomly, SecItemCopyMatching fails and then the sample code has resetKeychainItem which will basically reset your keychain.

```
    if (! SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)tempQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&outDictionary) == noErr)
    {
        // Stick these default values into Keychain if nothing found.
        [self resetKeychainItem];
    }
```

In our app, we noticed similar problems, and so now we are using

https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController to do all keyChain related functionality. Now it works very well.